# Add total with different in percentage in SRSS Power BI report builder

Tags: reporting-services, report, percentage, builder

I have a matrix with sales for district and store on the rows and different "time intelligence" on columns. I want to add totals. It works fine for values but for "YOY %" I don't want to sum the individual percentages of course - I want to have the total YOY for the values on the total row. How can I refer to these values? See the picture, the red value should be 109/77-1 = 42 % and not 183 %.

Any input is appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCl2O.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lelGy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: I didn't figure out a way to referring to columns generated from calculation groups (is it even possible?) so instead I created all the measures (columns) as seperate columns in the dataset. Then I can easily refer to them like YOY %:

```
=( Sum(Fields!Actual.Value) - Sum(Fields!PY.Value) ) / Sum(Fields!PY.Value)
```

and the totals is shown correctly.